# Format column result with % char in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL code that uses the lag function.

```
SELECT SalesAmount
    ,lag(SalesAmount) OVER (
        ORDER BY DATE
        ) AS PreviousDaylSales
    ,(
        SalesAmount - (
            lag(SalesAmount) OVER (
                ORDER BY DATE
                )
            )
        ) AS Difference
    ,(
        SalesAmount - (
            lag(SalesAmount) OVER (
                ORDER BY DATE
                )
            )
        ) / (
        lag(SalesAmount) OVER (
            ORDER BY DATE
            )
        ) * 100 AS PercentChange
FROM Sheet1$
```

Can I format the alias column `PercentChange` values with a % char?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use square bracket `[]`:

```
select . . . as [%Change]
from Sheet1$;
```

You can use sub-query to avoid repetition of same expression :

```
SELECT t.*, (SalesAmount - PreviousDaylSales) AS AS Difference,
       CONCAT('%', SalesAmount - PreviousDaylSales / PreviousDaylSales * 100) AS [%Change]
FROM (SELECT SalesAmount, lag(SalesAmount) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS PreviousDaylSales
      FROM Sheet1$
     ) t;
```

Comment: I was not clear with my intent, I want to format the values of that field with a % char :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

```
select ...
CONCAT(...*100, '%') as PercentChange
    from Sheet1$
```

Comment: I might have used concat in a wrong way, but I get the following error: Cannot convert a char value to money..
Isn't there a format function in SQL Server 2019

Comment: I think you can use CAST function before CONCAT to change data to char type.